# Python Dataframe: If First Column is Blank, Replace w/Value From Second Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, where-clause

The logic I'm trying to code is as follows:

If the 'new_column' field is blank, I want to pull in the value from the 'description' field in my data frame.

Below is the code I tried and the error I receive.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the value that should be assigned when your condition is `False`.  That's what `y` is in the error message.  See [`np.where docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> When True, yield x, otherwise yield y.

Currently, you only have:

```
np.where(condition, x)
```

If you want the `False` condition to leave the original value unchanged, do:

```
np.where(condition, x, original_value)
```

In your case:

```
np.where(df_EVENTS_6['new_column'] == '', 
         df_EVENTS_6['description'], 
         df_EVENTS_6['new_column'])
```